# InvalidCastException: Unable to Cast SqlString to SqlGuid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I feel like I'm losing my mind, why is this resulting in an `InvalidCastException`?

```
using (var dbContext = CreateDbContext()) 
{
    result = dbContext
            .Users
            .Where(m => m.UserId.Equals(userId)).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

In this case, "UserId" is a `uniqueidentifier` in SQL Server.  `userId` is a `System.Guid`.

UserId on the C# in the `DbSet` is also a `System.Guid`.

Where is it getting `SqlString` from?

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString' to type
>   'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid'.'

Comment: What is the entity User's type for UserId?

Comment: @Jasen It's a `System.Guid` on the C# side (In the `DbSet` entity).  Edited question for clarity.

Comment: have you tried SqlGuid.Parse(String)?

Comment: @phalanx I get the idea to work around the cast, the thing is I don't control the cast.  The `.Equals()` here is a `System.Guid` to a `System.Guid` in my code.  Both the local and the entity are Guids.  There are no `SqlString`s, that's why I feel like I'm losing my mind.

Comment: as it is here, I think your userId is sqlGuid, but you have sqlstring in your database. maybe you should check your db because you know everything is fine in your code.

Comment: same issue is happening with me and I can't figure out how this happens

Comment: Havent' tried it out myself, but can you try to do this as a workaround m.Property(p => p.UserId).HasConversion<System.Guid>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful that your entity class fully matches the database definition.

In my case, columns were being matched in order, and some of those in the SQL table were not defined in the C# entity class.

Answer (score -2):

I got the same issue. Problem would be Mismatch with DB Table fields and Model attributes. 
In DB having field1 as varchar but in model as guid. Check with all the db fields are matching exactly. Hope This helps.